# Cannot obtain values from the View (with MVC code first)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

This is how I populate the view from the viewmodel PersonInformation..

```
@model Client.Models.PersonInformation

<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>

    @foreach (var item in Model.MemberContacts) 
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.MemberContactDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ContactInformation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.MemberContactDescription)
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

And the ViewModel

```
public class PersonInformation
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public Address premiseAddress { get; set; }
    public Address billingAddress { get; set; }

    private ICollection<MemberContact> _MemberContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MemberContact> MemberContacts
    {
        get { return _MemberContacts ?? (_MemberContacts = new HashSet<MemberContact>()); }
        set { _MemberContacts = value; }
    }

    public  PersonInformation()
    {
        BIMemberService lib = new BIMemberService();
        ICollection<MemberContact> mcs = new List<MemberContact>();

        foreach (ContactLib itm in lib.ContactLibs())
        {
            MemberContact mc = new MemberContact();
            mc.MemberContactDescription = itm.Description;
            mc.ContactLibID = itm.ContactLibId;
            mc.ContactInformation = "test";
            mcs.Add(mc);
            MemberContacts.Add(mc);
        }
    }
}
```

But this one (which has an input text field), do not have a value on the post action.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => item.ContactInformation)
```

This is my post action.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonInformation(PersonInformation member)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Apply(member);
            return View("Requirements", member.person.MemberRequirements);
        }
        return View(member);
    }
```

Tracing down the code, the line below produces null value

```
member.MemberContacts.ContactInformation
```

Any advise, is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use editor for with an arbitrary item of a collection.

try reading [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx). It should give you some insight on collection binding

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder can only bind fields to simple properties on your model. You need to implement your own model binder.

Check it out at:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx